Solution of an IVP
Given
$$\frac{dy}{dx}+p(x)y=0$$
its general solution is
$$y=c\cdot\exp\left(-\int p(x)dx\right)$$
where $c\in\mathbb{R}$. Let $y(x_{0})=y_{0}$. My question is: how am I supposed to use the initial condition here?
What I did was: let $\mu(x)=-\int p(x)dx$. Then
$$y_{0}=c\cdot\exp(\mu(x_{0}))\Rightarrow c=y_{0}\cdot\exp(-\mu(x_{0}))$$
If $\exp(-\mu(x_{0}))=C$, we have
$$y=C\cdot y_{0}\cdot\exp\left(-\int p(x)dx\right)$$
PS: In my assignment, I have to choose the correct answer. There's an alternative with:
$$y=c\cdot y_{0}\cdot\exp\left(-\int p(x)dx\right)$$
i.e., with the same $c$ from the general solution. Shouldn't be a different constant?

I do not like both answers. With definite integrals the solution is simply $y(x) =y_0 \cdot\exp\left(-\int_{x_0}^x p(t)dt\right)$.

@MartinR to be honest, me neither. But There's no alternative like yours.

You're correct. $c=C$ is only possible if $y_0=1$.

@Gwen the anti-derivative $\int p(x),dx$ is only defined up to an additive constant. We don't even know what function $y$ they mean by those formulas. The only way to pin down $y_0$ is to get rid of that hideous $\int p(x),dx,.$

In general, using definite integrals for integrating factors and separation of variables makes the dependence on initial conditions much clearer. I think that this isn't done in most intro classes because students are more comfortable thinking in terms of antiderivatives, but the cloating integration constant can become a pain in problems like this
